# Pasar varias variables por cookies desde JavaScript a PHP

Tags: php, javascript, cookies

Estoy intentando pasar varias variables por cookie desde javascript a php, pero me salen que están indefinidas. Si trato de pasar solo una variable, si funciona, supongo que tendré que tratarlo como un array, pero no se como tratarlo.

**JavaScript**

```
function modificarFormacion()
{
    var tipo = document.getElementById("tipo");
    var categoria = document.getElementById("categoria");

    document.cookie = "tipo="+tipo.value;
    document.cookie = "categoria="+categoria.value;
}
```

**PHP**

```
 <?php
    $tipo = $_COOKIE['valor'];
    $categoria = $_COOKIE['categoria'];
    echo $tipo;
    echo $categoria;    
?>
```

Si lo hago solamente con tipo o con categoría, si me muestra en el PHP el valor de la variable.

¿Como puedo entonces solucionar el problemas de pasar variables variables desde JavaScript a PHP?

Comment: Las cookies son almacenadas en el navegador, no en el heap de cada lenguaje. Deberías poder acceder desde JS y PHP a ellas, indiferente de donde las hayas creado.

Comment: Si creo solo una cookie y la visualizo en PHP funciona, pero más de una, me sale para cada cookie valor indefinido

Comment: ¿has probado a enviar las dos variables en una misma cookie en vez de dos cookies con un &?

Comment: Solo un detalle: $tipo = $_COOKIE['valor'];  debería ser $tipo = $_COOKIE['tipo'];  ¿no?

Comment: Si sí, ha sido un fallo de copy paste @LuiscYm

Comment: @asantana cómo puedo hacer eso?

Comment: @MarioGuiber me he dado cuenta de que es lo mismo que lo que haces pero sólo ejecutando un cookie. He probado tu código y me funciona bien, sólo cambiando valor por tipo como dijeron antes. Prueba a limpiar las cookies del navegador y si no es eso el problema debe estar en otra parte del código